# startsWith endsWith matches contains regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm iterating through an array list of voice data to decipher if the user answered 'yes' or 'no'. Simple hey...

This is the initial check I have to detect an unclear response that contains both 'yes' and 'no'. It works perfectly, but just looking at it, I know I should be embarrassed to post it and it can be greatly simplified!

```
    if ((element.toString().startsWith("yes ")
    || element.toString().endsWith(" yes")
    || element.toString().contains(" yes "))
    && (element.toString().startsWith("no ")
    || element.toString().endsWith(" no")       
    || element.toString().contains(" no "))) {

    // I heard both yes and no - inform user I don't understand
```

I want the user to be able to accept or decline using whatever natural speech they desire and therefore need to consider the unlikely eventualities of the following appearing in the array data:

- yes no
- sey on
- yes knocking
- yesterday no
- yesterday knocking
- bayes theorem porno

I've been through so many regular expression posts and tutorials, but no matter what I do, I cannot find a solution that works better than the posted code. The white space [\\s] being there or '|' not, I can't resolve...

I thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want just the word "yes" or "no" (i.e. "bayes theorem porno" and the "yesterday" ones *don't* match) then you can use `\b` as a boundary character in a regex: [`Pattern` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), [Boundaries tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Assuming you're already lower-casing the input then this should work:

```
Pattern yes = Pattern.compile(".*\\byes\\b.*");
Pattern no = Pattern.compile(".*\\bno\\b.*");
...
bool matchesYes = yes.matcher(input).matches();
bool matchesNo = no.matcher(input).matches();

if (matchesYes == matchesNo) {
    ... //Do "invalid answer" here -
    //we either matched both (true, true) or neither (false, false)
} else if (matchesYes) {
    ... //Do "Yes" here
} else { //Else matches No
    ... //Do "No" here
}
```

Test code:

```
private static Pattern yes = Pattern.compile(".*\\byes\\b.*");
private static Pattern no = Pattern.compile(".*\\bno\\b.*");
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestMethod("yes"); //Yes
    TestMethod("no"); //No
    TestMethod("yesterday"); //Bad
    TestMethod("fred-no-bob"); //No
    TestMethod("fred'no'bob"); //No
    TestMethod("fred no bob"); //No
    TestMethod("snow"); //Bad
    TestMethod("I said yes"); //Yes
    TestMethod("yes no"); //Bad
    TestMethod("no yes"); //Bad
}

private static void TestMethod(String input) {
    System.out.print("Testing '" + input + "': ");
    bool matchesYes = yes.matcher(input).matches();
    bool matchesNo = no.matcher(input).matches();

    if (matchesYes == matchesNo) {
        System.out.println("Bad");
    } else if (matchesYes) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I can't envisage how it would be used to omit surrounding letters OR white-space. Could you possibly elaborate please? EDIT - Just seen your update, checking now - Thank you

Comment: `\b` means "word boundary" and basically matches the point where the next character is anything that isn't a word character (`\w`) including the beginning and end of the line, so "no", "fred no bob" and "fred-no-bob" should match, but not "fred non bob". Try it somewhere like http://www.regextester.com/ (but without the escaped slashes - so just `\bno\b` on a lot of regex testing sites)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the regextester - I've been looking for something like that! I'm about to test in my application and will come back and mark the answer as the correct after I've put it through its paces! Thanks again.

Comment: I had to change to: Pattern yes = Pattern.compile("\\byes\\b"); But it doesn't work? It doesn't detect the word yes anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I always forget that Java's Matcher.matches() has an implicit "^" and "$". I've fixed the code now.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I've market your answer as correct. However, the example strings "yes no" or "no yes" always return YES. I would need to check IF yes.matcher && no.matcher. The format of && or || or ! is similar to the long method in the opening code, and I'm wondering if you have the correct and most concise solution for completeness? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've fixed the "yes no" issue now using the shortest version I can come up with - create patterns, create matchers, check if they match on string and use `if..else if..else` for the three conditions. There may be some minor performance benefits to doing `Matcher noMatcher = no.matcher(input);` once and then `noMatcher.reset(input);` before you do the `.matches()` test instead of creating a new matcher each time, but I don't know how much.